# How to use function with variable in R?

Tags: r

in R,the pdf function can save graph in `c:/test`:

```
pdf("c:/test")
```

I want to make a variable substitue pdf ,how can i make it run ?

```
str<-"pdf"
str("c:/test")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get() does this:

```
get(str)("c:/test")
```

Answer (score 2):

`s = "pdf" ; do.call(s, list("c:/test"))`

or in two steps,

```
cl <- call(s, "c:/test")
eval(cl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the function specified by the name in `str` with `match.fun`:

```
match.fun(str)("c:/test")
```

By the way: It is not a good idea to name an object `str` since this is the name of a basic function in R.